# How can I make a telegram bot send the dice sticker?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm doing a bot that sends messages with the respective command, the easy text message I'm able to send but not an animated sticker.

I've been trying to use the `message.reply_sticker` and the `reply_dice` to send the dice emoji and know which outcome will be but I can't seem to be able to send anything, what should I put as a parameter? I tried to find the `file_id` but it just comes out as "dice".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your bot to send a dice, you'll need to use the [`sendDice`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#senddice) method.

No parameters (except `chat_id` are required), but you can set `emoji` to use a custom emoji (see documentation)

---

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<MY-BOT-TOKEN>/sendDice?chat_id=132456
```

---

Regarding the 'outcome', Telegram Bot API will return a [`Message`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) object, which in this case holds the [`Dice`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#dice) object which will tell you the outcome:

```json
{
    "ok": true,
    "result": {
        "message_id": 835,
        "from": {
            // ...
        },
        "chat": {
            // ...
        },
        "date": 1693323452,
        "dice": {
            "emoji": "",
            "value": 1
        }
    }
}
```

---

Since you've tagged the [python-telegram-bot](/questions/tagged/python-telegram-bot) library; the `sendDice` is available on the `Bot` class.

For more information and examples, see the relevant [documentation](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.sendDice).

Comment: How can I implement this method? Like where do I call it

Comment: Depends on the library you are using. Check the documentation about the available methods. I've added a link to the python-telegram-bot docs.